# Calculating day of the week from csv files, how to select one field in csv file

Tags: python, parsing, csv, pandas

I am trying to check a date value in each CSV file in a directory in order to calculate the weekdays.

The code below for calculating the day of the week works

```
import datetime
eventdate = "2/18/2014"
month,day,year = (int(x) for x in eventdate.split('/'))
day=datetime.date(year,month,day)
print (day.strftime("%A"))
filename = day.strftime("%A")
print filename
```

When I place it in a for statement for processing all of the csv files, the doesn't work. I get an error `Series object has no attribute split`

```
csvfiles = os.path.join(directory, '*.csv')

for csvfile in glob.glob(csvfiles):

    filename = csvfile
    no_ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    df = df[df["ORGANIZATION"]!="WPPL"]
    df = df.sort('MEETING START TIME')

    #getting the day of the week
    date= df["DATE"]
    month,day,year = (int(x) for x in date.split('/'))
    day=datetime.date(year,month,day)
    print (day.strftime("%A"))
    weekday = day.strftime("%A")
    print weekday
```

I understand that this is because the variable `date` is a series, so it can't be split as in the first chuck of code. Since each csv file will have the same date, all I need is the date value from the second row (first row contains header info) of the date column.

How I get choose a specific field in a csv file using pandas so I can get a single value and then do the split to get the day of the week?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like df['DATE'] is returning something other than a string. Try print(type(df['DATE']) to see what it is. Or just try casting to string, ie: str(df['DATE']).split('/')

Comment: Looks like it is returning [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#series)

Comment: @user590028 - Both result in  `cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects`

Comment: Sorry matt -- df['DATE'] is not a string, and therefore you cannot use split(). You're going to have to massage your data before trying to work with the date.

Comment: How can I select just one field from each csv file, then, so I would end up with a string?

Comment: I used `numpy.split`

`datesplit = numpy.split(date,4) 
  print datesplit[0]`

This gives me a single instance of the object:

`4 12/13/13
Name: DATE, dtype: OBJECT`

How do I pull just the `12/13/13` from that object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To retrieve the first row value use this

```
df["DATE"].irow(0)
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you! That numpy.split turned out to be a rabbit hole.